# Extend monthly data series to weekly data series in R

Tags: r, date

I have a monhtly data series and would like to extend it to a weekly series, using R.

I already created an empty weekly data frame and merged it with the time series with monthly data. Then I used the `na.locf` function which replaces all `NA` values with the value preceding it.

```
weekly.data <- merge(monthlyTS, enmptyweekly)

weekly.data <- na.locf(weekly.data)
```

This works well. However, there are some weeks which belong to two months: e.g. a week starting `2010-09-28`. For this week, I don't want the September value, but the weighted average of September and Octover value (`3/7*Septvalue + 4/7*Octvalue`).

Is there are formula to get this result?

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: It did, thank you very much :)

Comment: Good to hear. When an answer meets the requirements of the question, or is the most helpful among a series of answers, it is customary to [mark it as 'accepted'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  This is done by clicking the check mark just below the downward arrow on the upper left of the relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate thought was to extend it to daily and from there take weekly averages. It seems to work, but there might be simpler/quicker solutions around.

```
library(zoo)
par(mar=c(2, 2, 2, 1), mgp=c(3, 0.6, 0), mfrow=c(3, 1), cex=0.8)

mo <- seq(as.Date(1), as.Date(100), by="month")
zoo.mo <- zoo(seq_along(mo), mo)
plot(zoo.mo, type="b", pch=16, cex=0.5, main="monthly data")

zoo.da <- merge(zoo.mo, zoo(, seq(start(zoo.mo), end(zoo.mo)+15, by="day")))
zoo.da <- na.locf(zoo.da)
plot(zoo.da, type="b", pch=16, cex=0.5, main="daily data, constant interpolation")

zoo.we <- rollapply(zoo.da, 7, mean, by=7)
plot(zoo.we, type="b", pch=16, cex=0.5, main="weekly average")

weekdays(start(zoo.da))
```

[image]

It would take a little tweaking to get exactly as you want it. For example in this case the first day is a Friday, and so the week is taken to begin on Friday. A little trimming would change this to Monday, Sunday or whatever. The +15 bit in the merge command is there only to make sure that the final value (4) got carried over to the weekly data.